# Using distcc across two ssh servers

Tags: ssh-tunnel, distributed-computing

For those who do not know, "distcc" is a program that provides an infrastructure for remote compilation. I compile the source code for a software called FreeCAD, a lot. It takes about 4 hours to build the whole thing on my laptop. And the laptop makes my "lap" hot as hell! :-)

So, I would like to use "distcc" to remotely compile things in two computers I have access at the university.

I would like to use distcc through SSH. The "distcc" application works out of the box using SSH instead of client/server TCP port bindings. I want to use two servers A and B to do the compilation.

It happens that A and B are NOT accessible from outside the university. To access the computers A and B, I need first to ssh to a PUBLIC server. That is, from home, I have to access PUBLIC using ssh, and from PUBLIC, use ssh again to access A and B.

What is the recommended way to configure ssh/distcc for this setup?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

Set up `~/.ssh/config` so that connections to `A` and `B` use the option `JumpHost PUBLIC`. This will then be transparent to everything that does `ssh A` (including distcc, git, sftp, &c.)

```
Host A B
    JumpHost PUBLIC
```

Custom port numbers, domain names, or usernames can also be specified in the same way (for 'PUBLIC' as well as 'A' and 'B').

```
Host A B
    User foo
    JumpHost PUBLIC

Host PUBLIC
    User foobar
    Port 1234
```